# Android game reccomendation for electronics

Tags: android

I would like someone to reccomend me a android game regarding electronics (medium or advanced level game, no low level).

Backstory of the reason im not looking it up on my own:

I am in the hospital diagnosed with covid. They dont share their wifi here so I am on data, and cant browse all the time on the web to study nor download and test many games. I feel good enough so that I can play a game but not so good on studying a pdf/book (which I will try to do though).

Comment: what kind of a game? ... how would it relate to electronics? ... something that would require you to design a circuit?

Comment: anything. Even questions/answers-only game, multiplayer game, whatever. Just a reccomendation so that I know its not buggy

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios This is the only one I've played and can recommend: [KOHCTPYKTOP](https://www.zachtronics.com/kohctpyktop-engineer-of-the-people/). It's fun. I can't say if there is an Android version, though. That one was free. The same author makes a paywall version that I've not played: [shenzhen-io](https://www.zachtronics.com/shenzhen-io/). I'd expect it to be better, though, and would be willing to pay the price. Whether or not this would help you out, I've no idea. But I appreciate what's going on with you right now and this is the best I can think of, for now. Best wishes!

Comment: shenzhen-io is pretty good, but it is more of a low-level programming puzzle game than electronics. I am not aware of any game that does electronics.